# Nexus 4 end of support

Tags: updates, nexus-4

I think I've read that Nexus 4 will not receive monthly security updates any more. But I couldn't find the official information, other than [this general page](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/4457705). Can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nexus devices will also receive updates for security issues documented in our Public Nexus Security Bulletins for at least the following periods:
>
> - Three years from when the device first became available on the Google Store
> - Or, 18 months after the device stopped being sold on the Google Store

[Source](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/4457705)

As Nexus 4 was released on November 13th 2012 it is outside this time frame and will likely not receive many more monthly updates.